# Using libcurl to http-post

Tags: c++, libcurl

I followed this [example](http://curl.askapache.com/c/simplepost.html) to create a http-post but it only seems work for less than 1000 characters for post. How may i specify to post large data?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE_LARGE instead of CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE in

```
 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, (long)strlen(postthis));
```

Comment: I am not sure about your exact requirement, but if you need to post a file or something there are different examples in the same website which I am sure you must have checked. Are you getting an error?